# Is the book's proof complete for -- If $(a,b)=1,$ => $\exists s,t \in \mathbb {Z}$ s.t. $as +bt = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $(a,b)=1$ then $\exists s,t \in \mathbb {Z}$ s.t. $as +bt = 1$.

In the book by Pollard, Diamond titled "The Theory of Algebraic Numbers", there is a proof in the initial pages for proving the above theorem.

Proof (Th. 1.2) takes for the set of numbers given by $ax + by$, the smallest value positive combination with $x = s, y = t$, and the value of that $d = (as +bt)$. In the next step, the proof takes $b = dq' +r', 0 \le r' \lt d$. For constructing this last equality, the proof takes help of the division algorithm in Th. 1.1, that states : $a = bq +r, 0 \le r \lt b$.

The issue is how can it be directly taken to hold that : $b = dq' + r'$ from the division algo. without introducing proof for : $d \le b$. I mean that at that point, it is not shown that $d$ can attain values less than $b$.

Comment: This is a result of [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

Comment: In the division algorithm these are different $a$'s and $b$' s ! I think you're confusing the notations because they're the same but since it's different proofs/theorems, the notations represent dofferent things

Comment: If $b<d$, then $b=d\cdot0+b$. There's no need to assume $d\le b$ (provided, of course, that $b\ge0$).

Comment: According to the division algorithm, if $b$ is any integer and $d$ is any positive integer, then we can find integers $q$ and $r$ such that $b=dq+r$ and $0\le r\lt d.$

Comment: @egreg I 'earlier' (not after your responses) supposed that author should have given examples with a lattice or by numerical examples to instill this confusing idea, as I know $b$ can be bigger than $d$. What I mean is for a beginner, it is confusing to imagine a linear combination is less than the smaller of the two values (of which it is a linear combination), In fact, I should have framed question better, it is about not instilling details about the value set taken by $d$.

Comment: @jitender Actually, I find this a very bad proof of Bézout”s identity: it is nonconstructive, for one thing, whereas a constructive proof is much more useful, with the introduction of the extended Euclidean algorithm. I'll add a comment to my answer, though.

Comment: I hope that an approach that is constructive will automatically take at least one example or symbols (for a general sense), and I feel that this is what you mean too. This is lacking in non-constructive approach, and cannot be filled unless a change of approach to constructive is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The division with remainder $A=Bq+r$, with $0\le r<B$ doesn't need that $A\ge B$. Indeed, if $0\le A<B$, we directly have
$$
A=B\cdot 0+A
$$
and $A$ has the required property for the remainder by assumption.

So, you don't need to prove that $d\le b$. The division $b=dq'+r'$, with $0\le r'<d$ is always possible provided $d>0$, which it is by construction.

Actually, in the case when both $a$ and $b$ are positive (otherwise the proof is trivial), it is *obvious* that $d\le b$, because $b$ is a positive linear combination of $a$ and $b$, since $b=a\cdot0+b\cdot 1>0$.

---

I don't agree with books that present this proof, which is highly nonconstructive. Using the extended Euclidean algorithm, not only the existence of the greatest common divisor is established, but also an *efficient* method for computing it is provided.

Comment: I hope that an approach that is constructive will automatically take at least one example or symbols (for a general sense), and I feel that this is what you mean too. This is lacking in non-constructive approach, and cannot be filled unless a change of approach to constructive is done.

Comment: @jitender When I present the Euclidean algorithm, I often use the two numbers $1837100231809$ and $43126750060172161$ (obtained by mixing the prime factors of $2^{32}+1$ and $2^{64}+1$, the first two nonprime Fermat numbers). Computing the gcd with the Euclidean algorithm takes just a few minutes with pencil and paper (or, maybe, a pocket calculator). Since the least prime factor is $641$, factorization would take *much* longer.

Comment: So, you mean your example of using first two composite Fermat numbers to show finding Bezout's coefficients using EEA, to illustrate the significance of  the constructive approach.